# gamlss: best family to fit bounded "linear" distributions

Tags: r, gam, gamlss

I have a distribution that looks almost linear (can be slightly concave or slightly convex) between two positive boundaries;

I tested many families in the gamlss package but cannot find anything that fits well here.
The best solution I have is so far is to estimate the boundaries beforehand, and use trunc() to create truncated regressions (then using exponential distributions). However the boundaries vary with X, so I need to estimate them beforehand with a quantile regression, I'd like to know whether there exists another general family that could work better.

Comment: that's a pretty odd distribution. Where does it come from? Do you want to fit the distribution itself to a sample, or do you need to do a linear model with this distribution as the conditional distribution of the response (i.e. do you have covariates?).  In general for a bounded distribution, the maximum likelihood estimates of the min/max bounds will be equal to the *observed* min and max values.

Comment: I have a complicated dynamic model that generates it; But at the core there is the exponential of a uniform(0,1) variable, taken to some power. 
I have covariates, including continuous covariates, which is why it's hard to directly take the sample min/max (and why for now I'm doing quantile regressions to get it). I want to estimate the conditional distribution of Y | X.

Comment: Seems tricky.  Do you want to estimate e.g. shape and boundaries both as linear (or log-linear or other link functions) of the covariates?  I'd think `exp(U^p)` would have domain (0,Inf); where do the variable min/max bounds come from in your data generation process?

Comment: This might end up being more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ...

Comment: It's a dynamic model of consumption smoothing over time with a shock each period. Quite complicated to explain where the boundaries come from but they are there though ^^

Comment: Exactly I want to estimate the shape and boundaries as linear/log linear function of X. Right now i m doing a first quantile regression (for min and max) and then fitting a truncated exponential to the data. But I would prefer another more general distribution because the exponential is VERY sensitive to min/max mispecification

Comment: I could show how to do this as a general MLE problem. It might be a little bit tricky because any parameters for the min/max that result in boundaries that *don't* contain allo of the observed values will have a likelihood of zero ... any chance of a [mcve] with some data?

Comment: Thanks! I know how to code it as general MLE. I just wanted to know whether a known family existed/could be used for this kind of distribution. I've now tried all the options in gam.lss and it seems that (sadly) it does not :/ I'll try to make a simple reproducible example later.

Comment: I doubt it. A beta distribution with flexible scale and bounds would probably work (i.e. a random variable distributed as `c1 + c2*Beta(shape1,shape2)`, but I don't know if that's been implemented or not.